# C#-Linq: Ignore case when comparing using string.equals in linq

Tags: c#, linq, string-comparison

How to use `StringComparison` properties in the below code?

```
string _strVariable = "New York";
//nestList is nested list, list of list of objects, city below is an object, not a string 
var _countVar = nestList
  .SelectMany(list => list)
  .Count(city => string.Equals(city, _strVariable));
```

Tried below but they don't work, throws an error.

```
var _countVar = nestList
  .SelectMany(list => list)
  .Count(city => string.Equals(city, _strVariable,StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));

var _countVar = nestList
  .SelectMany(list => list)
  .Count(city => string.Equals(city, _strVariable,StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
```

Comment: What is the `nestList`?

Comment: *Throws errors* isn't very informative. Please post the actual Exception that is thrown. Is it LINQ to SQL or LINQ to objects? In other words is there a call to database ?

Comment: Did you try `String.Equals(_strVariable, city, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)`

Comment: Which error did you get?

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski - Am getting ""Object reference not set to an instance of an object." error.

Comment: Can you share the `nestList`? Did you cast it properly, if it's _list of list of objects, city below is an object, not a string_ If `city` is `object`, your code will no compile, because you can't compare the string and object

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski - Yes it`s an object, that`s why I had to use string.equals.

Comment: try to use `city.ToString()` in `Equals`

Comment: are you sure nestList is not null or contains null as one of sublist?

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski - It doesn`t work, throws error ""Object reference not set to an instance of an object.". If I dont put I get "cannot convert object to string".

Comment: @Anu - No it`s not null.

Comment: @DeSon please, share the complete code sample

Comment: No, you should do this `city.Name` or something like that to compare with `_strVariable`

Comment: @Pavel - Am getting data from an api which is internal accessible only.

Comment: is city an `object` or custom type ? Could you please share minimal reproducible code ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this way

```
String.Equals(_strVariable, city, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
```

Or use `.ToLower` or `.ToUpper` method, However, It's not a good way to cause the performance problem.

```
city.ToUpper() == _strVariable.ToUpper()
```

**Updated**

You can not compare object / custome type with a string type. You can do this

```
.Count(c => string.Equals(c.City, _strVariable,StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
-- Let's say You want to compare the City or CityName with the _strVariable
```

Comment: Please explain why you think the order of arguments in `string.Equals` matters.

Comment: I mean the OP can try `StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase` option. And the order doesn't a matter.

Comment: @Phong: city is an object, can not use toupper().

Comment: No, you should do this `city.Name` or something like that to compare with `_strVariable`

Comment: _nestList is nested list, list of list of objects_ You can't do that without cast, if list item is an `object`

Comment: So that's why I suggest OP that `c.City` or `c.CityName` or `c.Name`. Obviously, The OP need to give us more details information.